# Why aren't SXA rendering variants available for the default "Page Structure" renderings?

Tags: sxa, content-editor, presentation

For nearly all of the default renderings in SXA, there's an associated rendering variant. And if I wanted to add a variant, in the Content Editor, I can go to `presentation > rendering variant`, and duplicate an existing variant and modify it as needed. This is not the case for any of the "Page Structure" renderings.

I wanted to create a variant for the "Container" rendering, so I tried right-clicking on `Rendering Variants` and selecting `Insert from template` and using the existing template found in `/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Page Structure/Rendering Parameters/Container` -- but even this threw an error: `Field control has failed to render: index was outside the bounds of the array`.

Why don't "Page Structure" renderings allow variants and is there a way around it?

Comment: To add rendering variants to a Container you will have to do some costume code and extend the component.

Answer (score 1):

The `Page Structure` components are not variant components. If you look at the underlying code of something like the `Container` vs `Promo` you will see that the controller is different. The promo uses a `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Controllers.VariantController`, internally this will use the `VariantsRepository` and the view model is a `VariantsRenderingModel`. These do all the work of getting the rendering variants for the component.

A `Container` component builds off the `DynamicPlaceholdersController`. Components built off this are not designed to use Rendering Variants.

#### Container with rendering variants option:

If you want to create a "Container" like component, that uses rendering variants. The easiest way would be to clone an existing rendering variant component.

The first question to answer is, do you want your `Variant Container` to have a datasource item or not. If you do the `Promo` is the best to clone. If not, then clone the `Page Content` component. They both use the same razor view, but the `Page Content` component is already setup to not use datasources.

Clone the required component and call it something like `Variant Container` and then you can create your rendering variants for that. You will need to make sure that you add a `Placeholder` in your rendering variant.

Now you have a `Container` component that can have variants.

Notes: The new `Variant Container` will not have exactly the same markup as the existing `Container` component. It will have some extra markup around the rendering variant markup that all variant components have.