# XM Cloud component with dynamic placeholder

Tags: xm-cloud, sxa-jss

I wanted to try and create a custom container component such that it can be placed many times on the page and I can add components to it. I was having a problem at the time of seeing it in Experience Editor. Currently using the https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head template.

I follow the approach suggested here in order to create a custom container component in order for it to have variants. [Why aren't SXA rendering variants available for the default "Page Structure" renderings?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27410/why-arent-sxa-rendering-variants-available-for-the-default-page-structure-ren). What I did was clone the `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/JSS Experience Accelerator/Page Content/PageContent` component using the script.

The component has in the `Experience Accelerator` section, in the `Other properties` field, the value of `IsRenderingsWithDynamicPlaceholders` set to `true`. In the `Layout Service` section, in the `Layout Service Placeholder`, I have selected the newly created placeholder settings item I mention below.

I created a placeholder settings using  `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/JSS Experience Accelerator/Placeholder Settings/Placeholder`. The placeholder key is `custom-container-{*}`.

I added the Variant and Default variant definition item in `/sitecore/content/mySite/Presentation/Headless Variants/CustomContainer`. Also made the rendering available in the Experience Editor.

Finally I implemented the component view. I used as base the https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head/blob/main/src/sxastarter/src/components/Container.tsx.

```
export const Default = (props: ComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
   const phKey = `custom-container-${props.params.DynamicPlaceholderId}`;
   return(
       <div className="custom-wrapper">
         <Placeholder name={phKey} rendering={props.rendering} />
      </div>
   );
}
```

I try to add one to Experience Editor and it successfully renders. However if I close it and then open it again, I get the error `A rendering error occurred: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'attributes').`. Inspecting the console I also found this warning `Placeholder 'custom-container-1' was not found in the current rendering data.`

I am currently struggling to solve this issue and am not sure of the recommended practice for this.

**NOTE.** If applying the suggested fix of updating the JSS in `package.json`, and get errors like `File '/src/sxastarter/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts' is not a module`, `node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/types/index.d.ts' is not a module` and `Cannot find namespace 'JSX'`. I got it fixed by closing the code editor and restarting the machine (just in case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in JSS 21 and has been fixed in JSS 21.0.5.

The bug was that all dynamic placeholder keys must be called `container-{*}` - this was hard coded into the `PlaceholderCommon.tsx` file in JSS that resolves the dynamic placeholder key with the layout service JSON coming from the GraphQL call. This is why the out of the box components like the `Container` work ok.

Here is a link to the PR that fixed the issue: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/pull/1278

To make sure that you don't get this problem, update your `package.json` file to use JSS 21.0.5 for the following packages:

```json
"@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs": "^21.0.5",
"@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli": "^21.0.5",
```

Then re-install your npm packages and you should be able to create your custom placeholder keys.

Comment: Thank you so much, This fixed the issue of not being able to render the custom container component. I am now having an issue on the OOTB components as well as mine of `File '/src/sxastarter/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts' is not a module`, `node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/types/index.d.ts' is not a module` and `Cannot find namespace 'JSX'`. The version I was working with is `21.0.2`

Comment: Please open a new post for further questions and mark this one as the answer if it solved the initial problem :)

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Many thanks for letting me know :).